# Select specific names from list of dataframes in R

Tags: r

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(names=letters[1:10],name1=rnorm(10,1,1),name2=rexp(10,2))

list <- list(df,df)

vec_name <- c("f","i","c") # desired row names
```

I would like to select per list rows given the `vec_name` names:

Desired outcome:

```
[[1]]
      names      value1    value2
   6   nd:f   -1.6323952 0.3117470
   9   nd:i    1.8270855 0.2475741
   3   nd:c    0.6978422 0.4695581   # the ordering does matter; must be as seen in vec_name

[[2]]
      names      value1    value2
   6   ad:f   -1.6323952 0.3117470
   9   ad:i    1.8270855 0.2475741
   3   ad:c    0.6978422 0.4695581
```

**Desired output 2:** Is in dataframe, which would be I believe just `do.call(rbind,list)`:

**However** the clean names from **vec_names** should be used instead.

```
      names      value1    value2
   1      f   -1.6323952 0.3117470
   2      i    1.8270855 0.2475741
   3      c    0.6978422 0.4695581 
   4      f   -1.6323952 0.3117470
   5      i    1.8270855 0.2475741
   6      c    0.6978422 0.4695581
```

I have tried `sapply`; `lapply` ... for example:

```
lapply(list, function(x) x[grepl(vec_name,x$names),])
```

**EDIT** : PLEASE SEE THE EDITED QUESTION ABOVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. The warning message was saying:

```
Warning messages:
1: In grepl(vec_name, x$names) :
   argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Reason is that you provide a `vector` to `grepl` which is expecting a `regex` (see `?regex`). What you want to do is to `match` the contents:

```
lapply(list, function(x) x[match(vec_name,x$names),])
```

Which will give you a `list` of `data.frame` objects. If you want to combine them afterwards just use:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(list, function(x) x[match(vec_name,x$names),]))
```

Or you use `ldply` from `library(plyr)`:

```
library(plyr)
ldply(list, function(x) x[match(vec_name,x$names),])
#   names       name1     name2
# 1     f  2.01421228 0.4489627
# 2     i  0.28899891 0.8323940
# 3     c -0.01746007 1.5309936
# 4     f  2.01421228 0.4489627
# 5     i  0.28899891 0.8323940
# 6     c -0.01746007 1.5309936
```

And as a remark: avoid to use protected names like `list` for your variables to avoid unwanted effects.

**Update**

Taking the comments into account (`vec_name` does not match completely the names in the `data.frame`)you should clean first the names and then do the `match`. This is, however, assuming that your 'uncleaned' names contain the cleaned names with a pre-fix separated by a colon (':') (if this is not the case adapt the `regex` in the `gsub` statement):

```
ldply(list, function(x) x[match(vec_name, gsub(".*:(.*)", "\\1", x$names)),])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using `grepl` because the names is not so clean so `match` would not find the expressions. Is there any regex solution?

Comment: In this case I would 'clean' the names in the `data.frame` before (assuming that your 'uncleaned' names contain the cleaned names with a pre-fix separated by a ':'): `ldply(list, function(x) x[match(vec_name, gsub(".*:(.*)", "\\1", x$names)),])`

Comment: Waw what a mess question! Could you please submit this as an answer I would accept it immediately. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

for the first output :

```
output1<-lapply(list,function(elt){
                       resmatch<-sapply(vec_name,function(x) regexpr(x,df$names))
                       elt<-elt[apply(resmatch,2,function(rg) which(rg>0)),]
                       colnames(elt)<-c("names","value1","value2")
                       return(elt)
                       })

>output1
[[1]]
  names     value1    value2
6  nd:f -0.2132962 0.7618105
9  nd:i -0.6580247 0.6010379
3  nd:c  0.9302625 0.1490061

[[2]]
  names     value1    value2
6  nd:f -0.2132962 0.7618105
9  nd:i -0.6580247 0.6010379
3  nd:c  0.9302625 0.1490061
```

For the second output, you can do what you wanted to :

```
output2<-do.call(rbind,output1)

> output2

   names     value1    value2
6   nd:f -0.2132962 0.7618105
9   nd:i -0.6580247 0.6010379
3   nd:c  0.9302625 0.1490061
61  nd:f -0.2132962 0.7618105
91  nd:i -0.6580247 0.6010379
31  nd:c  0.9302625 0.1490061
```

Comment: Thanks, but please see the edit. The function `match` would not do it.

Comment: @Max, I modify my answer, does it work for you now ?

Comment: (+1) thank you for your affords, it works, but not sure how efficient is it. I up voted your answer but would not accept it for the efficiency point of view.